# How to use a private key for authentication with SSH?

Tags: ssh, authentication

Putty has this setting in `SSH/Auth`, but I don't see where to set it in [SSH](http://www.ssh.com/) .

Answer (score 1):

Private key settings for public-key authentication can be found in `Global Settings | User Authentication | Keys` in Settings dialog, as depicted in [SSH Tectia documentation](http://web2.www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/winhelp/40/keys.html#SSH2WIN-USERKEYS).

Comment: Seems it can't work with `.ppk` files?

Comment: No, `.ppk` is Putty's own file format. When you generate your keys in Putty, use the `Conversions | Export Openssh key` to save a `.key` file to be used with other programs. Or you can load an existing key to PuttyGen as well and convert it.

Comment: Tectia's SSH.com probably uses the `SSH.com` format (though I wouldn't be surprised if it got OpenSSH key support too)